# Como fazer Scraping de uma tabela e inserir os dados no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql, array, web-scraping, scraping

Bom, basicamente o que eu preciso é fazer um microservice que extraia os preços da cotação da soja dessa tabela: https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/soja/. E depois inserir os dados em um banco de dados.
Apesar de conseguir fazer o Scraping utilizando o código abaixo, não tenho ideia de como "filtrar" os dados do array para incluir na estrutura do banco de dados.

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/soja/');

preg_match_all('/<table class="table table-striped table-cotacao first-col-small table-menor">(.*?)(.*?)<\/div>/s',$content,$matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value){
    echo $value;
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

As colunas do banco de dados são apenas o local e preço.

Answer (score -2):

Opa, aconselho você a usar a biblioteca [Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm), daí você consegue interagir com o html de forma muito mais fácil, usando seletores css, que nem javascript.

No seu caso, poderia usar desse jeito:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://www.canalrural.com.br/cotacao/soja/');
$tableRows = $html->find('.table-cotacao tr'); // pega todas as <tr> dentro da .table-cotacao

foreach($tableRows as $tr) {
  $name  = $tr->find('td')[0]->plaintext;
  $price = $tr->find('td')[1]->plaintext;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado =D